# Gravity form API with python

Tags: python, api, wordpress-rest-api, gravity-forms-plugin

The documentation of the API is [here](https://docs.gravityforms.com/rest-api-v2/), and I try to implement this line in python

```
//retrieve entries created on a specific day (use the date_created field)
//this example returns entries created on September 10, 2019
https://localhost/wp-json/gf/v2/entries?search={"field_filters": [{"key":"date_created","value":"09/10/2019","operator":"is"}]}
```

But when I try to do with python in the following code, I got an error:

```
import json
import oauthlib
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

consumer_key = ""
client_secret = ""

session = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, 
client_secret=client_secret,signature_type=oauthlib.oauth1.SIGNATURE_TYPE_QUERY)

url = 'https://localhost/wp-json/gf/v2/entries?search={"field_filters": [{"key":"date_created","value":"09/01/2023","operator":"is"}]}'


r = session.get(url)
print(r.content)
```

The error message is :

```
ValueError: Error trying to decode a non urlencoded string. Found invalid characters: {']', '['} in the string: 'search=%7B%22field_filters%22:%20[%7B%22key%22:%22date_created%22,%22value%22:%2209/01/2023%22,%22operator%22:%22is%22%7D]%7D'. Please ensure the request/response body is x-www-form-urlencoded.
```

One solution is to parameterize the url:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://localhost/wp-json/gf/v2/entries'

params = {
    "search": {"field_filters": [{"key":"date_created","value":"09/01/2023","operator":"is"}]}
}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

response = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

But in the retrieved entries, the data is not filtered with the specified date.

In the official documentation, they gave a date in this format "09/01/2023", but in my dataset, the format is: "2023-01-10 19:16:59"
Do I have to transform the format ? I tried a different format for the date

```
date_created = "09/01/2023"
date_created = datetime.strptime(date_created, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

What alternative solutions can I test ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `urllib.parse.urlencode` function, so your code would looks like:

```
import json
import oauthlib
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

import urllib.parse

consumer_key = ""
client_secret = ""

session = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, 
client_secret=client_secret,signature_type=oauthlib.oauth1.SIGNATURE_TYPE_QUERY)

params = {
    "search": {"field_filters": [{"key":"date_created","value":"09/01/2023","operator":"is"}]}
}

encoded_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
url = f'https://localhost/wp-json/gf/v2/entries?{encoded_params}'


r = session.get(url)
print(r.content)
```

hope that helps

Comment: In the official documentation, they gave a date in this format "09/01/2023", but in my dataset, the format is: "2023-01-10 19:16:59"
Do I have to transform the format ?

Comment: I tested different formats, and there is an output, but it is not filtered. I wonder if the documentation is outdated. Or it is not possible, since all REST API work in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution with this code:

```
params = {
    'search': json.dumps({
        'field_filters': [
            { 'key': 'date_created', 'value': '2023-01-01', 'operator': 'is' }
        ],
        'mode': 'all'
    })
}

encoded_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)
url = 'http://localhost/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/1/entries?' + encoded_params + '&paging[page_size]=999999999'
```

I'm not really sure what permitted it to work as I'm an absolute beginner with Python, but I found that you need double quotes in the URL ( " ) instead of simple quotes ( ' ), so the solution by William Castrillon wasn't enough.

As for the date format, Gravity Forms seems to understand DD/MM/YYYY. It doesn't need a time either.